# Removing parent page in URL for one page

Tags: permalinks, urls

I have a page e.g.:

mysite.com/parent/child1/child2/page

And I want the URL to be:
mysite.com/page

But only for this one page ...  not the entire site. Is there a way to do this without using some of the WP plugins which seem to have issues according to the support forums.

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: [the_permalink filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) is likely where you'll want to look.

Answer (score -1):

Move this one page into the "root" of pages - set it's parent to (no parent)